# How to make Microsoft Entity Framework 6.0 bulk update/delete faster?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET application I am using Entity Framework 6 with SQL Server. As per my scenario I need to perform a bulk update (40k row at a time) and bulk delete operation (40k row at a time) with EF6. EF6's `RemoveRange` method seems very very slow and update takes forever. Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Use a bulk update library `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: is it free for production?

Comment: There are a fair few libraries around, and more then one way to achieve this, and yeah there are free versions. Is this for Core or Framework ?

Comment: https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-insert

Comment: its asp.net mvc. Not CORE. Can you suggest some of the available options?

Comment: I am aware of bulkInsert, thats for insert operation. not for update

Answer (score 0):

you should try a stored procedure to delete the items, stored procedures are much faster and pre-compiled form stored in SQL Server.

for reference to work with Stored Procedure please visit the link.
[Stored Procedure with Entity Framework](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/code-first-stored-procedure-entity-framework-6-0/)

Comment: I am already using this approach. But what should I use for updates?

Comment: That's one way, but OP is seeking _"...I need to perform bulk update(40k row at a time)"_ too